# How to stop refreshing gif image when reload

Tags: android, imageview, gif, android-glide, animated-gif

I am trying to load **.gif** file in `ImageView` using `Glide`. It loads properly but when the .gif file reload then the image refreshes like jerking or bouncing. But I want to stop this refreshing. The .gif file works properly in browser and photo viewer. My code is:

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(R.raw.white_bg1)
                .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(holder.imageview));
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(R.raw.white_bg1)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .skipMemoryCache(true)
    .into(holder.imageview)
```